# Probability to find $1$ in a random sequence of bits

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Given the random sequence of $N$ bit formed by $0$ and $1$ obtained flipping a coin and associating for example $1$ to head and $0$ to tail, suppose, after having built the sequence,  we randomically pick a number $k$ with a uniform probability and $1\le k\le N$, I have to calculate the probability that the number $k$ correspond to the position of a $1$ in the sequence. For example, if the sequence is $1010010100...$ and we pick $k=3$, in the sequence at position $3$ ther is a $1$. Same thing, if $k=6$ and so on. Thanks for any suggestion or answer.

Comment: So, you want the probability that a coin tossed landed a head?

Comment: Is it the same probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Either the number $k$ corresponds to a position of a 1 in the sequence or the number $k$ corresponds to a position of a 0 in the sequence.

Now how do you think the probability of the number $k$ corresponding to a position of a 1 in the sequence compares to the probability of the number $k$ corresponding to a position of a 0 in the sequence?

Comment: OK. The probability is the same for $0$ and $1$

Comment: Additionally, you can try the probabilities of all the combinations of 0 and 1s (which is the probability of all 1s, which is of 5 1s) and multiply it with by the probability of chosing a `1` in each of these combinations. Unsurprisingly the result is the same.

Comment: or even use independence of the value of each bit.